# Making a multi language site with Vue.js

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, vue-router

I am not so experienced with Vue.js but I am trying to make a multi language site with Vue.js and wondering if there is an effective approach to it. For instance I do not want to create duplicate views for each page I have. Is there any plugin to use for that and effective routing to handle the links?
This is what I came up with so far

On my vue page  Menu.Vue.

```
<v-list-item>
   <v-list-item-title>English</v-list-item-title>
</v-list-item>
<v-list-item>
<v-list-item-title>
 <router-link to="AnotherLanguagepage">
   AnotherLanguagepage
 </router-link>
</v-list-item-title>
```

Router's index.js

```
{
    path: '/page_language1',
    name: 'Display',
    component: Display1,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/page_language2',
    name: 'Display',
    component: Display2,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    }
  },
```

So I have views for the two languages but this is not scalable approach.

Comment: have you tried anything ? If yes then please provide code

Comment: You can checkout i18n with demo https://github.com/Jebasuthan/vue-vuex-vuelidate-i18n-registration-login-todo

Comment: Thanks @Jebasuthan I will take a look at it then. If any challenges popup will link up again

Comment: buddy, use NUXT read this https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/

Comment: @Ayudh, well that would have simplify some steps but the requirement I am working with require I stick with vuejs.Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: If that is the case, here's what you can do. Store the details of all text into language specific json files and then on app load, call the file from server for say: english, then store that file in a global state store such as VueX and then load the values throughout the app from VueX. Do you get what I'm saying?

Comment: Anyways Here's some videos that will help you out. They use vuejs only: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=vue+js+language+switcher+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look for a multi language site with Vue.js, you better use [Vue i18n plugin](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/).

No, you don't need to have several views or data inside your page/components. Basically, you'll have a lang folder with en.js, es.js... (as much lang as you need).

```js
// en.js

{
  "general": {
    "myListItemTitle": "My English title"
  }
}

// fr.js

{
  "general": {
    "myListItemTitle": "Mon titre français"
  }
}
```

```html
<v-list-item>
   <v-list-item-title>{{ $t('general.myListItemTitle') }}</v-list-item-title>
</v-list-item>

// $t is calling plugin and refers to currentLocale (en, es...). Example: en.js
```

Good luck !